# Structure a flattend array into a tree

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I have a list of objects with structure "id, name, parent_name" and I need to get a tree with names as a result.

Eg:

```
var employees = [];

var kirk = new Person(uuid(), 'Kirk', null);
employees.push(kirk);

var mark = new Person(uuid(), 'Mark', kirk);
employees.push(mark);

var tom1 = new Person(uuid(), 'Tom', mark);
employees.push(tom1);

var nick = new Person(uuid(), 'Nick', tom1);
employees.push(nick);

var ben = new Person(uuid(), 'Ben', tom1);
employees.push(ben);

var david = new Person(uuid(), 'David', ben);
employees.push(david);

var stacey = new Person(uuid(), 'Stacey', nick);
employees.push(stacey);

var corey = new Person(uuid(), 'Corey', nick);
employees.push(corey);

var tom2 = new Person(uuid(), 'Tom', stacey);
employees.push(tom2);

var julie = new Person(uuid(), 'Julie', stacey);
employees.push(julie);
```

Employees is my flatten list and I need the result like
`Kirk{Mark{Tom{Ben{David},Nick{Corey,Stacey{Julie,Tom}}}}}`

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if this is what you want:

```js
function uuid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

var Person = function(id, name, parent_name) {
 this.id = id;
  this.name = name,
  this.parent_name = parent_name;
  this.sub = [];
  
  this.addSubPerson = function(person) {
   this.sub.unshift(person); //Chnaged from 'push' to 'unshift'
    return person;
  };
  
  this.subPersons = function() {
    if(this.sub.length) { 
     var result = [];
        for(var i in  this.sub) {
            result.push(this.sub[i].subPersons());
        }
    return this.name + '{'+ result.join(',') + '}';
    }else {
     return this.name;
    }
  };
};

var employees = [];

var kirk = new Person(uuid(), 'Kirk', null); 
employees.push(kirk);

var mark = new Person(uuid(), 'Mark', kirk); 
employees.push(mark);

var tom1 = new Person(uuid(), 'Tom', mark); 
employees.push(tom1);

var nick = new Person(uuid(), 'Nick', tom1); 
employees.push(nick);

var ben = new Person(uuid(), 'Ben', tom1); 
employees.push(ben);

var david = new Person(uuid(), 'David', ben); 
employees.push(david);

var stacey = new Person(uuid(), 'Stacey', nick); 
employees.push(stacey);

var corey = new Person(uuid(), 'Corey', nick); 
employees.push(corey);

var tom2 = new Person(uuid(), 'Tom', stacey); 
employees.push(tom2);

var julie = new Person(uuid(), 'Julie', stacey); 
employees.push(julie);

for(var i in employees) {
 var employee  = employees[i];
  if(employee.parent_name != null) {
   employee.parent_name.addSubPerson(employee); 
  }
}

console.log(kirk.subPersons());
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But as I mentioned in the question, my expected answer should match Kirk{Mark{Tom{Ben{David},Nick{Corey,Stacey{Julie,Tom}}}}} and the result now is Kirk{Mark{Tom{Nick{Stacey{Tom,Julie},Corey},Ben{David}}}}

Comment: I have a function already defined as
function generateTree(employees) {


  var ceo = null; // Should be a PersonTreeNode object at the end;
  var managers = [];

  // YOUR CODE STARTS HERE

 
  // YOUR CODE ENDS HERE

  return ceo;
};

I get the flattend list in the function as a parameter 'employees' with all the other values like id already defined.

I just need to get the end result as Kirk{Mark{Tom{Ben{David},Nick{Corey,Stacey{Julie,Tom}}}}} and this string should be in ceo variable

Comment: The results are the same but the Order is different. However, I changed the code to match your result please check the snippet.